# gRPC python socket_mutator

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to make a gRPC client to use a specific exit interface.

For that, I am setting the value for the "socket_mutator" in the channel_arguments.
I defined a function that takes a socket as an argument and modifies it however I receive a:
TypeError: Expected int, bytes, or behavior, got <class 'function'>

Does someone know what should I place in the socket_mutator value instead?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could it be an error from some other place? Can you share code and complete stacktrace, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.